# Data Frame Join Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created 3 data frames and now I want to join them. However, I am running into this error: 
`NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsInternal$default$2()Z`

Here is the code:

```
val join1 = c1_df.join(ck_df, ck_df.col("APP_ID") === c1_df.col("ID"))

val joinFinal = join1.join(c2_df, c2_df.col("APP_ID") === join1.col("APP_ID"))

joinFinal.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

the following snippet works without any issues. are you sure `c1_df`, `ck_df` and `c2_df` are valid dataframes? This could also potentially be a spark versioning setup issue. make sure you are using the right version of Spark and your SPARK_HOME variable is set accordingly.

```
val c1_df = sc.parallelize((1 to 10)).toDF("ID")
val ck_df = sc.parallelize((1 to 10)).toDF("APP_ID")
val c2_df = sc.parallelize((1 to 10)).toDF("APP_ID")
val join1 = c1_df.join(ck_df, ck_df.col("APP_ID") === c1_df.col("ID"))
val joinFinal = join1.join(c2_df, c2_df.col("APP_ID") === join1.col("APP_ID"))
joinFinal.show()
+---+------+------+
| ID|APP_ID|APP_ID|
+---+------+------+
|  1|     1|     1|
|  6|     6|     6|
|  3|     3|     3|
|  5|     5|     5|
|  9|     9|     9|
|  4|     4|     4|
|  8|     8|     8|
|  7|     7|     7|
| 10|    10|    10|
|  2|     2|     2|
+---+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. The 3 data frames are working and I able to see the content. But when I do the join that's where I am running into the issue.